# Calculating distances between selected points from a single point in another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance

[image: Market Radius]

I'd like to calculate the distances for all competitors to a proposed operation within a certain radius.
Layers are:

- Competitors
- Possible Competitors
- Subject Property
- Market Radius

Ultimately, I want to be able to add a "weight" to each competitor based on distance from the subject property (red spot in the center of the radius).

Any thoughts?

I'm working in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Assign all competitors an attribute and give it all the same value. Assign this same attribute with the same value to your `subject property`. Then you will be able to use `hublines` to connect each `Competitors` to the `subject property` using `subject property` as `hub layer` with and `Competitors` or `Possible Competitors` as `Spoke Layer`. You will then be able to measure the length of those lines. To do so create an attribute for each line called distance and input `$length` as expression. Once that is done you can join the length attribute back to their corresponding points using `join attributes by field value`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is hublines a plug-in.  I can't find it under Vector Analysis.  Sorry for such simple questions.  I'm relatively new to QGIS.

Comment: you can find it in the processing toolbox. it is called `Join by lines (hub lines)`. You can open up the processing toolbox using `CTRL`+`Alt`+`T`

Comment: I really appreciate your help.